# Trouble creating web service with PHP NuSOAP

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

I'm trying to set up a simple web service but I'm having trouble. The service seems to be available, but I can't seem to return a response. Var_dump on $client shows a connection to the web service, but nothing comes back in response. No errors are caught either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

server.php

```
<?php
require_once ("lib/nusoap.php");
$URL = "https://www.domain.com";
$namespace = $URL . '?wsdl';

$server = new soap_server;
$server->debug_flag = false;
$server->configureWSDL('Test', $namespace);
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

function get_message($your_name)
{
    if(!$your_name)
    {
        return new soap_fault('Client','','Put Your Name!');
    }

    $result = "Welcome to ".$your_name .". Thanks for Your First Web Service Using PHP with SOAP";
    return $result;
}

$server->register('get_message');

// create HTTP listener

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
exit();
?>
```

client.php

```
<?php
$wsdl = "https://www.domain.com/webservice/server.php?wsdl";

require_once ('lib/nusoap.php');

$param = array("your_name" => "Liam");

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace" => true));

$response = $client->get_message($param);

if($client->fault)
{
    echo "FAULT: <p>Code: (".$client->faultcode."</p>";
    echo "String: ".$client->faultstring;
}
else
{
    echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why won't you use PHP Soap extension with built-in SoapClient and SoapServer? It's much faster, less buggy, more features and lots of examples.

Comment: I tried that based on your suggestion, but wasn't successful. I ended up switching this to JSON. The application I'm creating is fairly basic and the client will be written in .net. I've read about .net clients having trouble communicating with PHP servers via SOAP, so this was probably the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

There were bugs in the code of client and server files, I have updated the code

server.php

```
<?php
require_once ("lib/nusoap.php");
$URL = "http://www.domian.com/server.php";
$namespace = $URL . '?wsdl';

$server = new soap_server(); //added ()
$server->debug_flag = false;
$server->configureWSDL('Test', $namespace);
//$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

function get_message($your_name)
{
    if(!$your_name)
    {
        return new soap_fault('Client','','Put Your Name!');
    }

    $result = "Welcome to ".$your_name .". Thanks for Your First Web Service Using PHP with SOAP";
     return $result;
 }

$server->register('get_message',
                    array('request' => 'xsd:ArrayReq'), // ArrayReq is type for your parameters
                    array('return' => 'xsd:String'),
                    'urn:Test',
                    'urn:Test#get_message',
                    'rpc',
                    'encoded',
                    'show message'); // added request return array

// create HTTP listener

//$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service(file_get_contents('php://input'));
exit();
?>
```

Client.php

```
<?php
$wsdl = "http://www.domian.com/server.php?wsdl";

require_once ('lib/nusoap.php');

$param = array("your_name" => "Liam");
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl); // user nusoap_client() for creating client object
//$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace" => true));

$response = $client->call('get_message', $param); // use call() to call the server functions

if($client->fault)
{
   echo "FAULT: <p>Code: (".$client->faultcode."</p>";
   echo "String: ".$client->faultstring;
}
else
{
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

it's working!